# Proxy Facebook chat to bypass firewall

Tags: facebook, chat, xmpp, xiff

We built a flash application using XIFF XMPP to integrate with Facebook chat.

Problem is we found out a lot of firewalls out there do not allow Jabber (ports 5222, 5221).

So I was wondering if anyone tried to set-up a BOSH implementation (or something else) as a proxy to Facebook's chat for clients who are blocked by a firewall.

Thanks
Guy

Comment: We're just about to build the same thing. Is your code for sale?

Comment: You can contact me to guy dot tomer at attractv dot com

Answer (score 1):

How about [PunJab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab)?

> PunJab is a HTTP jabber client interface. It is a BOSH connection manager that
>   allows persistent client connections to a XMPP server.

Comment: @guytom Punjab is pretty mature and used a lot (Check out some of the Metajack blogs)

Answer (score 1):

Actually facebook xmpp chat works even with port 443